# What makes two functions have fundamentally different efficiency times in Big O notation

Tags: big-o, calculus, processing-efficiency

Today I was posed with the problem of ordering several functions based on efficiency and computing mathematically which functions would have the same Big O notation. Long story short, I ended up getting into a disagreement with my classmate as to whether or not there is a fundamental difference between a function with a run time of 2^n and on with a run time of n^(n/2).

I was taught that in Big O notation, leading coefficients end up being insignificant as n approaches infinity because they are just a vertical scaling of the same parent function, when n is huge, 6*n isn't really THAT different from n, as they both have the same parent growth rate, which makes sense. My argument followed that because this vertical scaling of the function was insignificant because it was simply a child function of the same thing, any constant transformation made would retain the overall parent function, so the child would have the same base growth rate and end up being simplified to the same notation (in this case O(2^n)).

My classmate made the point that

```
2^(n/2) = (2^(1/2))^n = sqrt(2)^n
```

....and because 1.414^n is quite smaller than 2^n as n approaches infinity, then it should be noticeably larger.

My classmate then proposed that two functions have different Big O notations if

```
lim((f(n)'s efficiency)/(g(n)'s efficiency)) as n->infinity 
    is either infinity (f(n) is bigger), or 0 (g(n) is bigger)

And because ((2^n) / (2^(n/2))) = ((2^(n/2) * 2^(n/2)) / (2^(n/2))) = 
    2^(n/2), approaches infinity, they must have a rate of change that is
    fundamentally different.
```

My classmate's theory of what makes two algorithms have different Big O notation clearly makes sense for linear vs linear, linear vs quadratic, and just about any other common situation, but then again, so does mine. Something that is a transformed linear function (meaning it is translated and or scaled vertically or horizontally, but not scaled by a negative number, zero, et cetera) will always have a Big O notation of O(n), because it is linear. Any quadratic function will end up being O(n^2) because the constants will become insignificant and only the n^2 term will matter, because it is a transformed quadratic. (works for other stuff too, you get it) Obviously, x^2 is fundamentally different from x^3, because you cannot scale a quadratic to match a cubic function, so they must be different enough to get their own categories in Big-O.

Clearly [at least] one of us is thinking about this the wrong way. I mean, either O(2^(n/2)) gets simplified to O(2^n) or it doesn't, right?

So which one (if either) of us is right, and why is the other wrong, and most importantly, how do we tell if two inefficiencies are fundamentally different in a situation like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial question compares 2^n and n^(n/2). It's easy to see than n^(n/2) is slower because at n=4 they are equal (16), and from that point on n^(n/2) is increasingly larger.

2^(n/2) is smaller than both of these. Effectively, where c is a constant and nc is n * a constant, nc^c < c^nc < nc^nc.

In the case of 2^n vs 2^(n/2), 2^n has a larger O because no constant can make 2^(n/2) keep up with it as n increases.